# Can setNextEvent() persist variables to be restored in prc?

Tags: coldfusion, coldbox

Can `setNextEvent()` persist variables to be restored in `prc` of the destination event?

Thanks.

Comment: What happened when you tried to do so?

Comment: @DanBracuk they just get restored in `rc`, not `prc` (private)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the built-in **persist** and **persistStruct** functionality only applies to the request collection (rc).  You could put in a ticket for this if you like:
https://ortussolutions.atlassian.net/projects/COLDBOX

In the mean time, you can easily accomplish this manually via Flash Ram:
http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/EventHandlers.cfm#Flash_Variables

Comment: Yes.  http://coldbox.ortusbooks.com/content/configuration/configuration_directives/flash.html

Comment: Brad -- link is no longer valid.

Comment: Thanks for the note, the new URL is https://coldbox.ortusbooks.com/content/full/configuration/coldboxcfc/configuration_directives/flash.html  Please note GitBook is down today so the link might not work at the moment.

Comment: Looks like the page moved again, this time to https://coldbox.ortusbooks.com/getting-started/configuration/coldbox.cfc/configuration-directives/flash. @BradWood You should create 301 redirects for the old URLs to avoid leading people (and search engines) into 404s. (Same applies to the link in your answer, btw.)

Comment: Sadly, GitBook is a 3rd party documentation platform that we have no control over so it's not an option for me to create redirects.  Gitbook had a recent huge update that broke tons of our stuff and we had to rework the docs again to fix everything.